# PyAv save audio and video togerther from stream to simple file

Tags: python, audio, video, video-streaming, pyav

Based on the examples from the documentation, I am trying to implement the recording of a stream in an .mp4 file. I can't start saving to a file **both** sound and video at the same time. Something one :)

```py
import av.datasets
from av.container import InputContainer, OutputContainer

input_: InputContainer = av.open("udp://192.168.1.68:8083?pkt_size=1316&overrun_nonfatal=1&fifo_size=50000000")
output: OutputContainer = av.open("remuxed.mkv", "w")

in_stream = input_.streams.get(audio=(0,), video=0)

out_stream = output.add_stream(template=in_stream)
for packet in input_.demux(in_stream):

    if packet.dts is None:
        continue

    packet.stream = out_stream

    output.mux(packet)

input_.close()
output.close()
```

https://pyav.org/docs/develop/cookbook/basics.html

Help me how can I do this? At the moment, it is possible to record either audio or video.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Recording input from UDP (with no container) may work, but it's not reproducible (it may not work). Would you like to get an example for remuxing MP4 input file to MKV output file? We may remux the following file, generated using FFmpeg CLI: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=500 -c:v libx264 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 100 input.mp4`. In case you want me to answer, please edit the question (replace `udp://192.168.1.68:8083?pkt_size=1316&overrun_nonfatal=1&fifo_size=50000000` with `input.mp4`).

Comment: I need to do the same, but with pyav with AudioFrame and VideoFrame as obejects (

Comment: I can't see how is it relevant to your question, since your question is about Remuxing.